# Get a category name from the id in the url using kusto query

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

I need to get the category name from category id using kusto query.

First i have got the most searched url from the website using the below kusto query and ran it in app insights logs

```
Requests
| where resultCode==200
| where url contains "bCatID" 
| summarize count=sum(itemCount) by url
| sort by count
| take 1
```

From the above query i got the result like
`https://www.test.com/item.aspx?idItem=123456789&bCatID=1282`

So for corresponding categoryid=1282 i need to get the category name using kusto

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator).

for example:

```
print input = 'https://www.test.com/item.aspx?idItem=123456789&bCatID=1282'
| parse input with 'https://www.test.com/item.aspx?idItem=123456789&bCatID='category_id:long
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[parse_urlquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseurlqueryfunction)

```
print url ="https://www.test.com/item.aspx?idItem=123456789&bCatID=1282"
| extend tolong(parse_urlquery(url)["Query Parameters"]["bCatID"])
```

| url | Query Parameters_bCatID |
| --- | --- |
| https://www.test.com/item.aspx?idItem=123456789&bCatID=1282 | 1282 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUSgtylGwVcooKSkottLXLy8v1ytJLS7RS87P1c8sSc3VSywuqLDPTPEEsm0NjYxNTM3MLSzVkpwTSzxdgAIWRkq8XDUKqRUlqXkpCiX5Ofl56RoFiUXFqfFAkwtLU4sqNYAMzWilQBBbISCxKDE3tSS1qFgpNloJYoxSrCYAlglq9IwAAAA=)

Answer (score -2):

Feedback to the OP query
**Not an answer**

1. KQL is case sensitive. The name of the table in Azure Application Insights is *requests* (and not *Requests*).
2. *resultCode* is of type string (and not integer/long) and should be compared to *"200"* (and not *200*)
3. *bCatID* is a token and therefore can be searched using *has* or even *has_cs*, which should be preferred over *contains* due to performance reasons.
4. URLs can be used with different parameters. It might make more sense to summarize only by the *Host* & *Path* parts + the *bCatID* query parameter.
5. *count* is a reserved word. It can be used as alias only if qualified: *["count"]* or *['count']* (or better not used at all).
6. *sort* followed by *take 1* can be replaced with the more elegant *top 1 by ...*

```
requests
| where resultCode == "200"
| project url = parse_url(url), itemCount
| summarize sum(itemCount) by tostring(url.Host), tostring(url.Path), tolong(url["Query Parameters"]["bCatID"])
| top 1 by sum_itemCount
```